# How to get computed values on GORM model?

Tags: go, go-gorm

So, I have a very simple query, that I was able to emulate in gorm, but now I am unable to read all the values to the model:

```sql
SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name ,
(select count(*) < 1 from other_table ot where ot.employee_id = e.id) as isBelowOne
FROM employees e ;
```

So the problem is that `isBlowOne` is a computed value that I don't want to store on the table, but to calculate it from the subquery.
This is how I build the subquery:

```golang
    subquery := r.DB.
                  Table("other_table").
                  Select("count(*) < 1").
                  Where("other_table.employee_id = employees.id").SubQuery()

    sql = sql.Select("*, ? as isBelowOne", subquery)
```

My problem now is making GORM read the field. I can't declare it as part of the model because I don't want to persist it on the database, so what are the options?
I didn't found anything about this on advance queries, what they call advanced are just sorts and where conditions, nothing like this.

Comment: Have you looked at [Field Level Permissions](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Field-Level-Permission). They enable you to add a field to your model which is read only, so it won't show up in insert/update queries. Haven't tried this myself, but is where I would start.

Comment: @EzequielMuns I just tried that a minute ago out of pure desperation and it worked. I read about them, but the docs says that such field will be completely ignored by gorm, not read not write.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I come up with.
First thing to fix is the field name on the query. GORM requires, by convention, that you use snake_case on your fields, so this is the correct way of doing the query:

```golang
sql = sql.Select("*, ? as is_below_one", subquery)
```

Then, just declare the field on the model, but make gorm ignore it:

```golang
IsBelowOne  bool `gorm:"-"`
```

According to docs this is called [Field-Level-Permission](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Field-Level-Permission), but confusingly enough it says that `gorm:"-"` will make GORM ignore it when writing and reading, making it virtually useless. However, in practice it works, so I guess this is just bad documentation.

Comment: Did you try the read only version: `gorm:"->"`? It would mean that whenever you query for your model you'd need to include the subquery.
OTOH, by creating a different model that embeds this one plus has the extra field and [Smart Select Fields](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Smart-Select-Fields) might give you the versatility you need.

Comment: @EzequielMuns thanks for raising those interesting points. My only doubt is: is it possible to relate or link the subquery to the structure that includes this field? I see the ability to skip the subquery appealing in some situations, but If I have to manually add it every time then it's probably not worth the risk.

Comment: I would look at using the `AfterFind` hook to query for the computed field. It's not ideal though, as it would mean two separate queries. It would be better if there was a `BeforeFind` hook that let you modify the statement as in [Modify Current Operation](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Modify-current-operation).

Comment: I guess that is the bad part about using ORMs, you can not fine-tune your queries. Thanks for pointing me to several interesting features.